# Adding multiple product at a time

Tags: android, in-app

i want to add multiple products in my product list at a time.I google a lot but didnot find anything.Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a batch of items to a product list using a CSV file, you first need to create your CSV file.Check this out- http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-form-add

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the In app bililng reference [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-list-setup), under the `Adding a batch of items to a product list` sub heading. At the moment however, adding subscription products in bulk is not supported.